# R.Java id error

Tags: android, facebook

can some help me here??
i am getting error in following line of code in R.java file
`public static final int login_user-fb=0x7f0d00bf;`

the identifier "-" is creating problem as you all know.

i have not declared this id anywhere in  my project, i am using facebook sdk in my project since than it is giving error.

things i have done to rectify the error  till now.
1.removed facebook sdk and rebuilt projct.
2.clean project
3.as you know i cannot edit R.java file, i tried doing everything but every time it is creating that code in my R.java file as whenever i run my project.
please help me out here.

Comment: Android drwables  and ids are not allowed to have "-" in them you have to rename the drawable with "_"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please check through your xml-files, and see that you have the correct naming convention for all your id's etc.

I am thinking of these type of naming errors:

```
 android:id="@+id/text-view-example"
```

and rename them to:

```
 android:id="@+id/text_view_example"
```

**OR**

Search in your project by right-clicking on 'app', in your left side panel (android-view), and click on 'Find in Path', and then type in that exact query, **login_user-fb**, and then replace them to *login_user_fb*.

Comment: i got it sorted Ludwing.  there was a xml file with that name that i missed to check.thank you.

Comment: **Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid comments like “+1” or “thanks”.** user will upvote & accept the answer if the problem is resolve by his answer no need to ask for that @LudwigS :)